# Unable to call LightBox plugin via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I am trying to use lity (by Jan Sorgalla) and the following is my use-case.

On the click of a button I call a Ajax function which should return a composed HTML and that should get shown in a lightbox modal view.

On successful return of the Ajax call I am doing the following

```
var instance = lity(response);
```

How do I use the above instance to open the lightbox?

I tried

```
$('#try').on('click', '[data-my-lightbox]', lity);
$('#try').trigger('click');
```

Try is some div just to create a trigger. This does not work.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Maybe try fancyBox, it would be as simple as `$.fancybox.open(response);` or `$.fancybox.open({src : response, type : 'html', opts : {}});`

Comment: thanks. will check. meanwhile got it working on lity. see answer below

Answer (score 0):

It was mentioned in the detailed notes of lity that I missed out. The following worked:

```
      var lightbox = lity();
      lightbox(response);
```

where response is the html result of the Ajax call